# refactoring Control Parameter

Tags: ruby, refactoring, reek

I'm using a tool for finding code smells in code called reek and I have a problem with one called Control Parameter

```
def place_ship(ship, start_position, orientation)
    @row = start_position[:row]
    @column = start_position[:column]
    ship.length.times do
        if orientation == :vertical
            vertical_place_ship(row,column,ship)
        else
            horizontal_place_ship(row,column,ship)
        end
    end
end

def vertical_place_ship(row,column,ship)
    self.grid[row][column].ship = ship
    self.grid[row][column].status = :occupied
    @row += 1 
end

def horizontal_place_ship(row,column,ship)
    self.grid[row][column].ship = ship
    self.grid[row][column].status = :occupied
    @column += 1
end
```

warning's content: [

```
55]:ControlParameter: Board#place_ship is controlled by argument 'orientation
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you look at the docs for Reek here http://www.rubydoc.info/github/troessner/reek/Reek/Smells/ControlParameter it actually mentions the Strategy Pattern as one solution. I don't know Ruby well enough to do a code example, but hopefully someone else can.

Answer (score 6):

'Orientation' is a flag value in *place_ship* method. Value of 'orientation' is not changing as the code executes. So no need to check it 'ship.length' times.

*place_ship* has only conditional logic and nothing else. This is unnecessary and *the conditional logic can reside outside*. You are ***passing in a flag, that tells the method what path to choose, conditionally***. This is the ***Conditional Coupling smell***. Generally do not pass in a conditional parameter to a method. Have 2 different methods for the 2 choices and name them aptly.

You already have aptly named *vertical_place_ship* and *horizontal_place_ship* methods. You can refactor it like this.

```
def <method_that_calls_place_ship>
// other code
    if orientation == :vertical
      vertical_place_ship(ship, start_position)
    else
      horizontal_place_ship(ship, start_position)
    end
// more code
end

def vertical_place_ship(ship, start_position)
    row = start_position[:row]
    column = start_position[:column]

    ship.length.times do
      self.grid[row][column].ship = ship
      self.grid[row][column].status = :occupied
      row += 1 
    end  
end
```

Similarly for horizontal_place_ship method.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the tool feedback, looking at your code, the only line that differ between the horizontal & vertical case is whether to increase @rows or @columns. An option could be:

```
def place_ship(ship, start_position, orientation)
    row = start_position[:row]
    column = start_position[:column]
    ship.length.times do
        self.grid[row][column].ship = ship
        self.grid[row][column].status = :occupied
        orientation == :vertical ? row += 1 : column += 1
    end
end
```

I removed the two (identical) methods, and just used the ternary operator ('?') to increase the correct variable after placing each ship part.

Comment: Orientation is being checked multiple times within the loop. But it's value never changes.

Comment: This still has the same code smell as the original code. You have only changed the structure of the conditional statement.